# vb.net why Val("&") produces IndexOutOfRangeException

Tags: vb.net, indexoutofrangeexception

Why `val("&")` gives a `IndexOutOfRangeException` (Index was outside the bounds of the array.) ?

Shouldn't it just return zero?

Is there a "fix" on this **so it will return zero**? I already have lots of `val(something)` scattered around a whole project, i don't want to add everywhere `if (something<>"&") Then`....

Also, are there more characters that will produce this kind of error when used in `val()`?

---

sample code
`Dim test As Integer = Val("&")`

p.s. i could just write a wrapper "myVal" function with a check `if (something<>"&") Then`  but i would like to know what causes this problem so i can have a reliable fix.

Comment: Read the documentation for `Val()`.

Comment: @Dan-o i did https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7beh1x9%28v=vs.90%29.aspx and i still cant get an answer. i can only assume it confusing its parsing with radixes or something, but its only a guess. care to explain or help, wise downvoters?

Comment: @Shaky: you got it.  If the string starts with & then the Val() function expects the next character to be an O or an H.. and since there is no character at position 1... IndexOutOfRange.

Comment: @Dan-o is ampersand the only "tricky" character?

Comment: Its the only one I know of.  I hate Val.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well after the downvotes (of the type "booo just read the documentation -1") and the guesswork on comments, i figured i have to **dig** for a good answer.

This is the implementation of `Val`

http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#Microsoft.VisualBasic/Conversion.vb,6492d8e784d2ae91

The problem begins here:

```
ch = InputStr.Chars(i)
If ch = "&"c Then 'We are dealing with hex or octal numbers
    Return HexOrOctValue(InputStr, i + 1)
```

As soon as the first non-space character (`ch`) is `&` it calls `HexOrOctValue` like this `HexOrOctValue(InputStr, i + 1)`

Check HexOrOctValue .net Implementation:
http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#Microsoft.VisualBasic/Conversion.vb,41d686eb6be390d9

The second parameter (which is passed like `i+1` from `Val`) is used **as an index of character on the `InputStr`.**

Of course, there will be no index at `i+1` if `i` is the index of **the last character.** So `HexOrOctValue` will trigger this error on this line `ch = InputStr.Chars(i) // i here has the Vals' i+1 value`

That's why `Dim test As Integer = Val(" &")` WILL produce the Index out of range error ...and accordingly `Dim test As Integer = Val(" & ")` will NOT produce the error (verified).

A fix? That depends on your flavor. I think the less intrusive way is a wrapper that just adds an extra character to make sure there is always a `i+1` index:

```
Public Function myVal(ByVal InputStr As String) As Double
    Return Val(InputStr + " ")
End Function
```

Well, this way the "bug" somewhat gets hidden under the rug, which is not the absolutely-strictly-defined "best" practice, but it is tiny enough to approve and keep things going.

p.s. "&" is the only character affected by this bug.